# C - construct max heap from given binary tree

Tags: c, heap, binary-tree

Given a binary tree:

```
typedef struct node
{
  int info;
  struct node *left,*right;
}node;
```

How to implement a recursive function `void heapify(node *root)` to construct a max heap from a binary tree given above?

Comment: Dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24801613/max-heapify-a-binary-tree

Comment: For each element in reverse-array order, sink it down.